# How to check if URL/ IP belongs to a zeus bot

Tags: network, malware, botnet

I have a set of URL's which *might* be Zeus hosts / C&C servers since my security appliance says so. Is there a way to check if these really belong to Zeus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Providing that you are looking for information already analyzed, and your question is not about the technical ways to identify a Zeus C&C Server, you can look at the following places:

- [malwaredomainlist.com](http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/)
- [malwaredb.malekal.com](http://malwaredb.malekal.com/)
- [exposedbotnets.com](http://www.exposedbotnets.com/)
- [scumware.org](http://www.scumware.org/index.scumware)
- [malc0de.com](http://www.malc0de.com/database/)
- [cybercrime-tracker.net](http://cybercrime-tracker.net/)
- [vxvault.siri-urz.net](http://vxvault.siri-urz.net/ViriList.php)
- [nothink.org](http://www.nothink.org/viruswatch.php)
- [botnet-tracker.blogspot.ch](http://botnet-tracker.blogspot.ch/)
- [atlas.arbor.net](http://atlas.arbor.net/summary/botnets)
- [marworm.com](http://www.marw0rm.com/references/botnet-tracking/)
- [zeustracker.abuse.ch](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php) (Zeus botnet tracker)
- [alienvault.com](http://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange/latest-threats)

Note that you can also use those places to look for many other threats / malicious activities than Zeus.

Answer (score 5):

First, you can look at the [abuse.ch zeustracker](https://www.abuse.ch/zeustracker/blocklist.php?download=ipblocklist) list.

Second, note that the abuse.ch list is the primary source for the [iblocklist.com](https://www.iblocklist.com/lists.php) zeus list.  You may also wish to look through some of the many other malware lists on iblocklist.com to check for other malware sites.

Separately, you can check to see on what basis your security appliance is making the determination - is it using a list (perhaps one of these)?  If it is using a list, which one, and how often does it update it?  Is it using traffic analsis (like Snort would) instead?

Answer (score 1):

When I get alerts of possible zeus infection from the security appliances, this is what I usually do:

1. check the URL with [zeustracker](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/index.php)
2. if the URL is not in the zeustracker db, check on [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/)
3. if there is detections, likely this is a malicious connection
4. Run a tcpdump on the connection to check the packets

zeustracker has a guide showing how to identify zeus malware, go take a look