# What sites give the latest information on security threats especially zero day malware

Tags: zero-day

What websites give the latest information on zero day malware or other exploits newly introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the information about zero-days, running malware or advanced exploits investigation (marketed as [Advanced Persistent Threats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_persistent_threat)) is privately owned by some commerical companies (such as [Mandiant](https://www.mandiant.com/) for ex.).

Apart of that, you can use the traditionnal vulnerability feeds like [CERTs](http://www.us-cert.gov/) or [CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/). 
A feeds list was posted in [this related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19980/where-can-i-get-security-breach-alerts) that might help you as well.

At last, I answered to [that question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51979/how-to-check-if-url-ip-belongs-to-a-zeus-bot/51989#51989) with a small list of websites tracking malware / threats seen in the wild:

- [malwaredomainlist.com](http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/)
- [malwaredb.malekal.com](http://malwaredb.malekal.com/)
- [exposedbotnets.com](http://www.exposedbotnets.com/)
- [scumware.org](http://www.scumware.org/index.scumware)
- [malc0de.com](http://www.malc0de.com/database/)
- [cybercrime-tracker.net](http://cybercrime-tracker.net/)
- [vxvault.siri-urz.net](http://vxvault.siri-urz.net/ViriList.php)
- [nothink.org](http://www.nothink.org/viruswatch.php)
- [botnet-tracker.blogspot.ch](http://botnet-tracker.blogspot.ch/)
- [atlas.arbor.net](http://atlas.arbor.net/summary/botnets)
- [marworm.com](http://www.marw0rm.com/references/botnet-tracking/)
- [zeustracker.abuse.ch](https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/monitor.php) (Zeus botnet tracker)
- [alienvault.com](http://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange/latest-threats)

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to this twitter Security List : https://twitter.com/theffernan/lists/it-security-list ( This is not mine .)

You will get almost all the feeds of the kind  which you are searching for .

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be a reddit user the following sub-reddits are of value and stay fairly up to date on new events:

http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/

http://www.reddit.com/r/Malware/

There are many other ones but these are two of the main ones that have a wider scope than the others. Would recommend exploring the sub-reddits that these two link to as well.